# Binding HttpClient 4.1 request to local address

Tags: java, sockets, httpclient

Getting error while binding HttpClient request through a specific localAddress

this is the code

```
    HttpParams httpsParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    ConnRouteParams.setLocalAddress(httpsParams, InetAddress.getByAddress(new byte[]{ (byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)43, (byte)98 }));

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpsParams);

    URL url = new URL("http://what-is-my-ip.net/?json");

    HttpGet method = new HttpGet(url.toURI());

    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);
    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int nbRead;
    while ((nbRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        bos.write(buffer, 0, nbRead);
    }

    is.close();

    System.out.println(new String(bos.toByteArray()));
```

and this is the error

```
Oct 26, 2012 10:48:57 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Network is unreachable: connect
Oct 26, 2012 10:48:57 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
Oct 26, 2012 10:48:57 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Network is unreachable: connect
Oct 26, 2012 10:48:57 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
Oct 26, 2012 10:48:57 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: Network is unreachable: connect
Oct 26, 2012 10:48:57 PM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: Retrying connect
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at utils.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:49)
```

Am i doing something wrong ?
Please help, i googled a lot but couldnt find anything on this.

Is this an OS related problem, im on win7 ?

Any help wld be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sry, but can't comment question, so i'll try to answer:
99% chance that problem in 192.168.43.98 interface, check it if he work good

PS: you can test it by curl:
curl --interface "192.168.43.98" http://what-is-my-ip.net/?json

Comment: $ curl --interface "192.168.43.98" http://what-is-my-ip.net/?json    
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: when 192.168.43.98 interface is down it shows **curl: (45) bind failed with errno 125: Cannot assign requested address**

Comment: so the trouble is in adapter or network with interface 192.168.43.98

Comment: It seems to be something at OS level, i tried binding a Socket like this **new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("www.google.co.in"), 80,localAddress,0);** it also resulted in **java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable: connect**, what could be the problem, code works fine when interfaces are tested individually with other interface disabled, do i need to change something at OS level to get Socket binding working.